# Unable to return a long integer from embedded Python to C++

Tags: python, c++

Hi I am trying to return a value (119599936) from the embedded python to C++

```
Py_Initialize();
PyObject* myModuleString = PyString_FromString((char*)"memory_leak_test");
PyObject* myModule = PyImport_Import(myModuleString);
PyObject* myFunction = PyObject_GetAttrString(myModule,(char*)"begin");
PyObject* args = PyTuple_Pack(1,PyString_FromString("CacheSetup"));
PyObject* myResult = PyObject_CallObject(myFunction, args);
double result = PyFloat_AsDouble(myResult);// <<<<<<<<< I guess thts where i'm goin wrong
std::cout << result << std::endl;
Py_Finalize();
```

I tried

```
unsigned long result = PyLong_AsUnsignedLong(myResult);
unsigned long long result = PyLong_AsUnsignedLongLongMask(myResult);
double result = PyLong_AsDouble(myResult2);
```

None of the above seemed to work for the when I try to return the number 119599936, the error i'm getting is

```
Exception SystemError: '..\\Objects\\longobject.c:739: bad argument to internal
function' in 'garbage collection' ignored
Fatal Python error: unexpected exception during garbage collection
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your code performs no error checking whatsoever, and you don't provide the source to the `memory_leak_test` module, it's anyone's guess what went wrong. My guess would be that `memory_leak_test` failed to import, or that `memory_leak_test.begin("CacheSetup")` raised an exception or returned `None` instead of returning a number like your code expects.

To debug this problem, rewrite with the following guidelines in mind:

- Check errors from Python/C functions that may return them. Whenever an error you can't handle appears, call [`PyErr_Print()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/exceptions.html?highlight=pyerr_print#PyErr_Print) and terminate current execution (unless you are expecting the error and want to handle it properly - in that case, call [`PyErr_Clear()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/exceptions.html?highlight=pyerr_print#PyErr_Clear) instead.)
- Invoke [`Py_DECREF`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/refcounting.html#Py_DECREF) on objects returned as [*new references*](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html#ownership-rules) once you no longer need them. Examples of these are the return values of `PyString_FromString`, `PyTuple_Pack`, and `PyObject_CallOject`.
- Learn of and use convenience functions such as [`PyObject_CallFunction`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/object.html?highlight=pyobject_callfunction#PyObject_CallFunction), [`PyObject_CallMethod`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/object.html?highlight=pyobject_callfunction#PyObject_CallMethod),  and [`PyImport_ImportModule`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/import.html?highlight=pyimport_importmodule#PyImport_ImportModule) which significantly reduce boilerplate code for creating temporary strings and tuples. The best way to find these is by perusing existing Python/C sources, such as those that come with Python.
- Use [`PyObject_Print()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/object.html?highlight=pyobject_print#PyObject_Print) to print intermediate results for debugging.

Here is a possible modification of your code according to the above:

```
Py_Initialize();

PyObject *module = PyImport_ImportModule("memory_leak_test");
if (!module) {
  PyErr_Print();
  return;
}
PyObject *result = PyObject_CallMethod(module, "begin", "s", "CacheSetup");
Py_DECREF(module);
if (!result) {
  PyErr_Print();
  return;
}
printf("got result of type %s\n", Py_TYPE(result)->tp_name);
PyObject_Print(result, stdout, 0);
putchar('\n');

Py_DECREF(result);
Py_Finalize();
```